# Build project in Qt Creator using CMake from snap

Tags: qt, cmake

Ubuntu 20.04

I just want to use default snap and apt versions

Qt Creator 4.11.0 from apt:
`sudo apt install qtcreator qt5-default`

CMake 3.24.0 from snap:
`sudo snap install cmake --classic`

If I open the project, it gives an error:

```
Running /usr/bin/snap /home/fresh/Downloads/test -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/usr -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/usr/bin/qmake in /tmp/QtCreator-BsxNPO/qtc-cmake-BcKQdVpk.
error: unknown command "/home/fresh/Downloads/test", see 'snap help'.
CMake process exited with exit code 64.
```

Any change to make it work properly without building CMake from source or installing newer version of Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/cmake/current/bin/cmake /usr/bin/cmake
sudo ln -s /snap/cmake/current/bin/ccmake /usr/bin/ccmake
sudo ln -s /snap/cmake/current/bin/cpack /usr/bin/cpack
```

In Qt go to Tools > Options > Kits > CMake in Manual set Path:

```
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Go back to Kits tab, in CMake Tool choose added new CMake

Relaunch Qt. It works